# stochastic fast vs. williams r

Tags: technical-analysis

I'm sort of new to technical indicators, and I was looking at stochastic fast and williams r.  As I understand the definitions, they are:

```
C = the most recent closing price
L14 = the low of the 14 previous trading sessions
H14 = the highest price traded during the same 14-day period
(the period can be changed from 14 for more sensitive or smoother results)

Stochastic Oscillator
%K = 100[(C - L14)/(H14 - L14)]

Williams %R
%R = -100[(H14 - C)/(H14 - L14)]
```

Doesn't this mean that `%R = %K - 100`?  In which case, why have both?

Thanks.

-Erik

Comment: Yes. There is a simple relationship between the two, as mentioned here  https://stockcharts.com/school/doku.php?id=chart_school:technical_indicators:williams_r

Comment: Ok.  I guess I just found it odd that if you do the algebra, it honest-to-goodness reduces to %R = %K -100.  If you solve both equations for 'C', then 'C' can be removed.  Then solve for %R.  @AlexC, if you put this in an answer, I'll mark it correct.  If anyone's interested, I'll post the math.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both measures express where C is within the interval from L14 to H14.

%K ranges from 0 when C is at the 14 day low, to 100 when C is at the 14 day high.

%R ranges from -100 when C is at the 14 day low, to 0 when C is at the 14 day high.

So they are actually linked by a simple linear relationship. We can derive it as follows:

$\%K = 100[(C - L14)/(H14 - L14)]$

This can be reversed to express C as a function of %K:

$C=L14+\%K/100(H14-L14)$

We can plug this into the definition of %R

$\%R=-100[(H14 - C)/(H14 - L14)]=-100[(H14-L14+\%K/100(H14-L14)/(H14-L14)]=-100+\%K$